# What is the equivalent of $provide.decorator in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I am looking for what the equivalent of $provide.decorator is in Angular 2+, or something similar that could get similar results. Preliminary research has turned up empty.

The reason I'm looking for this is because, in angularJS, we used it to modify $state.go to conditionally check a variable set by the app and determine if we should prevent the route from modifying history (and thus appearing in the back button). I am looking for something similar in angular 2+.

I know for this specific case, router.navigate(..., {skipLocationChange: true}) is an option, but it would involve editing many classes and I would like to avoid that.

Thank you in advance!